# how to download a file from azure storage account to a temporary file variable in power shell

Tags: powershell, download, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, temporary-files

$f=New-TemporaryFile

$f = Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Context $ctx -Container "name" -Blob "blobname" -Force
 I have tried it using the above cmndlets

Answer (score 1):

I would save the file using Get-AzureStorageBlobContent to the $env:temp directory and then use Get-Content to read it to a variable.

There's an open feature request regarding this at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/3665

You might be able to succeed with mikepowell's solution provided in the GitHub issue:

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $azConnectionString
$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $storageContext -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName
$byteArray = New-Object Byte[] $blob.Length
$blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadToByteArray($byteArray, 0)
```

Comment: I would like to pass the path of the temporary file at the end to an invoke command